# MySQLI: in_array isn't properly working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently creating a demo registration system (I will note that this isn't an assignment or homework now) and I want to have the "Add to Cart" be disabled if the user already purchased the item (and that item only) previously and it's reflected in the database

```
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//Query to get item information
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY eventid");// WHERE sort = '$sort' 
$remaining = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders");
$obj_r = $remaining->fetch_object(); // obj_r means objects remaining

//Query to disable already purchaced items
$QgetSignups = $mysqli->query("SELECT s.eventid, o.status FROM signups s JOIN orders o ON s.orderid = o.orderid WHERE s.userid = $userid AND o.status = 1");            
$signedup = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QgetSignups))
    //while($row = $QgetSignups->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    array_push($signedup,$row["eventid"]);
}

if ($results) { 

    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        echo '<div class="product">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj->image.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="product-content"><h4>'.$obj->name.'</h4>';
        echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->description.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        echo 'Price: '.$currency.$obj->price.' | ';
        echo 'Items Left: '.$obj->max.' | ';
        echo '<input type="hidden" style="width:20px;height:15px;" type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />'; // OLD CODE TO DISPLAY QTY BOX: Qty: <input style="width:20px;height:15px;" type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />';

        if($signupAmount[$row['eventid']] >= $row['max'])
        {
            echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        }

        if(in_array($row['eventid'],$signedup))
        {
            print_r($signedup);
            //echo '<button DISABLED class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        }
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->name.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

}


?>
```

The script currently attempts to check if the item that was purchased matches "eventid" (which is the number that represents the item number). As of right now I am attempting to do so by pushing the item number into an array, and then using an in_array to check against it, but the in_array isn't working if I use the method `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QgetSignups))` (It pulls the array numbers, but in_array doesn't properly check to see if it exists) and if I use `//while($row = $QgetSignups->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))`, array_push doesn't gather the values, but the in_array method attempts to show the array (despite it being empty).

Comment: Also you should almost always use the third parameter of in_array($array, $value, true);
To make it do a strict comparison, when you can. I've had some really weird problems out of in_array before, when not setting it to strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not iterating over $row in the current while loop where the below code exist.

```
if (in_array($row['eventid'], $signedup)) {
    print_r($signedup);
    //echo '<button DISABLED class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
}
```

I'm not sure how your database schema is setup but maybe it should be the following:

```
if (in_array($obj->eventid, $signedup)) {
    print_r($signedup);
    //echo '<button DISABLED class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver. That was the exact solution :). It's been driving me nuts for a week now.

Comment: glad I was able to help. happy coding!